# How to deep copy nested list in dart?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, nested-lists, deep-copy

How can I create a copy of a nested List in dart? In this code changes I make to the copy are also changed in the original

```
List board = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]];
List boardCopy = List.from(board); // create copy of the board

boardCopy[0][0] = 1; // change copy

print(board); // print original board

OUTPUT:
  [[1,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]] <-- it has changed the original board!!!
```

Answer (score 7):

I worked it out:

```
List boardCopy = board.map((element) => List.from(element)).toList();
```

Comment: how would u do the same for a map (key value) ?